# Python Interprocess w/REST Interface options

Tags: python, ipc

Is there any tool/library for Python that will aid in interprocess communication, while keeping the API/client code easy to maintain?

I'm writing an application wherein I own both the server and the client portion, but I'd like to make it expandable to others via a REST interface (or something similarly accessible).  Is my only options to write the boilerplate connective tissue for REST communication?

Answer (score 1):

The REST interface should be implemented with small functions that call the actual Python API, which you will implement any way.

If you search here, on SO, the most frequent recommendation will be to use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) to expose the REST interface.

There are libraries around that will try to turn the methods of a class into REST paths, and such, and those may save you a couple of hours on the onset, but cost you many hours down the road.

This morning I coded a backend service that way. The [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) calls to the external service are hidden by a module so the business logic doesn't know where the objects come from (ORM?), and the business logic produces objects that a simple [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) layer consumes to produce the JSON required by each matched URL.

```
@app.route("/api/users")
def users():
    return json_response(
        api.users(limit=request.args.get('limit', None)),
    )
```

A one-liner.